# What code in CSS and/or HTML makes no spaces in text?

Tags: html, css, spacing

How do you make no spaces between top and bottom text...
For example:

```
<p>Hi</p>
<p>Bye</p>
```

Like, how do you put no space in the middle of that?
I could use a CSS of HTML code...

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want? It sounds like you just want `display: inline`.

Comment: Okay well I'll try the "display:inline" code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a margin between the paragraphs. To get rid of it, you'll need to set the margin via CSS:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

To get "Hi" and "Bye" on the same line, you'd either change the `display` of `p` elements, or change the markup:

<sub>change display:</sub>

```
p {
    display: inline;
    //or
    display: inline-block;
}
```

<sub>change markup:</sub>

```
<p>Hi Bye</p>
```

Comment: @JoshC, maybe, but OP wasn't very clear.

Comment: Thanks, that will help I think.

Comment: Yea, the inline code helped... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<p>Hi<br/>
Bye</p>
```